# footer background not displaying full page in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code i want to make background color to display full width.when I am giving width to 100% but it's not displaying.
can any one help me

```css
.footer {
color:#EEEEE; 
font-style:italic;
position: relative;
  
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 43px;

background:#000000;
}
.footer .container{
background:#000000;
width:100%;
}
.footer p{
margin:0;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:600;
float:left
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Address:- D-000, Text Text, Text. Text, Text (Text), Text-000 0000, Text <br>
Mobile : +91 000-000-0000 Phone : + 0000 0000 0000 Fax : + 0000 0000 0000 <br>
Email: abc@gmail.com</p>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 OLISVELL, Inc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your "footer" part in your css is never closed (missing bracket), and, when you look at your code snippet, then it seems like your footer is displayed... full page or not!^^

Comment: you need to post the entire html code of the page. The footer is most likely in a page wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: see this]

Your markup should look like this.

Comment: @care567 .. you are adding this footer inside 2 parent containers. Put this footer div in "bann-bot" container. hope this helps.

Comment: @care567 see the image I have added

Comment: if i add the code like that every content was displaying full width

Comment: what not working? dont expect us to resolve your code magically :D .. we helped as much as we can. at least let us know what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83117/discussion-between-care567-and-era).

Answer (score 1):

Here your `body` is taking default `margin` of 8px, removing that will solve the problem. Set

```
body {
margin: 0; 
}
```

See the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to css reset .

```css
.footer {
color:#EEEEE; 
font-style:italic;
position: relative;
  
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 43px;

background:#000000;
}
body, html{margin:0;padding:0;}
.footer .container{
background:#000000;
width:100%;
}
.footer p{
margin:0;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:600;
float:left
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Address:- D-000, Text Text, Text. Text, Text (Text), Text-000 0000, Text <br>
Mobile : +91 000-000-0000 Phone : + 0000 0000 0000 Fax : + 0000 0000 0000 <br>
Email: abc@gmail.com</p>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 OLISVELL, Inc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> [**What Is A CSS Reset?**](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)

Comment: @care567 now cut your footer code and paste after .news1 div

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your footer is contained in another element which constrained its width. Take it out, like so:

```
<div class="bann-bot">
    ... <!-- where the footer used to be (about 3 levels deep) -->
</div>
<!-- where the footer needs to be -->
<div class="footer">
    ...
</div>
```

Then add styling as appropriate. Hope I helped!